# LWC Slider formatting range with thousand separators

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds

Has anyone managed to format the range output on a LWC Slider? I'd like the range numbers to have thousand separators, and possibly currency signs as well.

Currently, this:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-m-vertical_medium">
        <h1 class="slds-text-heading_small">Basic Slider</h1>
        <p class="slds-text-body_regular">A slider lets you specify a number between two specified values. If a range is not provided, the slider defaults to a minimum of 0 and a maximum of 100.</p>
    </div>
    
    <lightning-slider label="Volume" value={val} max="100000"></lightning-slider>
</template>
```

shows as:

[image]

I'd like it to show as 0-100,000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to override the format, unfortunately. However, you can use the [open-source version](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/slider) and customize it to your liking.